# Validate Captcha

Tags: php, jquery

I am using following code to access the captcha

```
<img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id="captchaimg" ><br />
<label for="message">Enter the code above here :</label>
<input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">
```

I am using jquery validation in the form, not able to validate the captcha with the right image, how can i validate it ?
I have the below code for could be able to get it properly

```
if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
  strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
    {
        //Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively.
        //if you want case sensitive match, update the check above to
        // strcmp()
        $errors .= "\n The captcha code does not match!";
    }
```

Guide me Please ! Thankyou

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right of the text area. Worth a read, as is the information available from the **[?]** button above the text area. **Edit**: Looks like Kolink fixed it for you, but as this is your fourth question, it's coming on to time you were formatting things correctly yourself. Also, I added the `php` tag for you, as validation of this sort **must** be done server-side and your second code block looks like PHP.

Comment: Regret !  Now please guide me ?

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using ? (add a link if poss)

Comment: using the code from the following url--
http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html/comment-page-6#comment-38694

Comment: @PujaVerma No - i mean the jquery validation ? what are you using ?

Comment: yes the same as it is like 6_letters_code !! Not able to validate the captcha in the following url - http://demo.hiccupsolutions.com/contact_form/form.php

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rule like this :

```
rules: {
    6_letters_code: {
       required: true,
       remote: "process.php"
    }
}
```

where `process.php` is the PHP URL you want to use to check the CAPTCHA - all you need to do is return `true` or `false`.

[Details of the `remote` option here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options)

Your PHP should be something like :

```
if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_GET['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
   echo "false";
} else {
   echo "true";
}
```

It seems that the `remote` option uses `get` instead of `post`. There is a [live example here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/) you can use Firebug (or any browser debugger) to see the AJAX being sent/received

Comment: @ManseUk---yes it works thankyou, but if i missed any of alphabets or missed type it, its accepting it clearly ? can i have that validation also ?

Comment: @PujaVerma Yes just return `false` from your PHP - update your question with your new PHP function as it is now

Comment: if somehow i made it in this format `6_letters_code: {
      required: false    
             },` , the validation did not work for me, my validation is worked for me now but i need to validate the captcha image with the captcha field, like if the captcha contains "z123fg" and then during form filling i have miss typed it to "z321gf", then it should be validate on that time, i think you have got me right now ?

Comment: yes i do have the code like 

`if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_GET['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
   echo "false";
} else {
   echo "true";
}
 ` 

where i have to put it to get the validation on captcha values  ?

Comment: @PujaVerma in the php file you specify in your `remote` option in your validation as shown in my answer

Comment: yes i specified but as soon as i specify, the send button did not work-- i have create a process.php and put the whole code in that and take that process.php as on remote,not worked :(